# Accessing a Value in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this massive array that looks like this somewhat:

```
[field_sidebarhtml] => Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (   [value] => Custom Sidebar Content
                    [format] => filtered_html
                    [safe_value] => 
Custom Sidebar Content
                )
        )
)
```

**==> Actually, Here is the entire Array http://psdesignzone.com/fullarray.txt**

I need to access the 'safe_value' in the variable array which is named '$page' how would I do that?

Comment: I think you might need to add some more information about why you are needing this value, and the greater context of where you are using it, but try `$safe_value = $array['field_sidebarhtml']['und'][0]['safe_value']; echo $safe_value;`

Answer (score 2):

based on fullarray.txt

```
$tmp_obj = $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7]['body']['#object'];
$val = $tmp_obj->body['field_sidebarhtml']['und'][0]['safe_value'];
```

Note that '#object' is a stdClass instance instead of an array is not clear from your question text, only in fullarray.txt.

(edited to find the first instance of safe_value with "Custom Sidebar Content")
A second instance occurs at

```
$tmp_obj = $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7]['field_sidebarhtml']['#node];
$val = $tmp_obj->body['field_sidebarhtml']['und'][0]['safe_value'];
```

There are probably more.

Comment: That didn't quite get what I was looking for, safe_value that says "Custom Sidebar Content" is what I am trying to access it is in an array sub element called field_sidebarhtml.

Is there a formatter anywhere to make this huge array easier to manage?

Comment: Good effort, I took a stab at this and got lost halfway. It's a pretty ridiculous array, seems like something may not be right with the code that generated it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch this kind of structure comes up in MVC frameworks. I wrote a tree class and a set of visitor classes to deal with it at work.

Comment: I guess I meant that you shouldn't need to get the array value this way, not that the code that generated it is ridiculous - my mistake. I hope for your sake you arent using any code like in your answer in any of your projects :)

Answer (score 1):

`print $bigarray['field_sidebarhtml']['und'][0]['safe_value']`

that will output:

> Custom Sidebar Content